# How to show error component when any error come in angular 6?

Tags: javascript, angular

I am trying to show error component when there is error in app .I make `interceptor` which check is there any error is service response . If yes it will redirect to `error` component but currently it not redirecting why here is my code
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ctwnid?file=src%2Fapp%2Ferror.intercepter.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpEvent, HttpErrorResponse, HttpInterceptor, HttpHandler, HttpRequest } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

import {catchError, map} from 'rxjs/operators';


@Injectable()
export class ErrorInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(private router: Router) {}

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return next.handle(req).catchError(
      (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        if (err.status === 401) {
          this.router.navigate(['/error']);
        }
        return Observable.throw(err);
      }
    );
  }
}

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, 
  RouterModule.forRoot(routes),
  HttpClientModule,FormsModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent, 
  HelloComponent ,ErrorComponent],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ],
  providers: [TestService,TestResolver,
  {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: ErrorInterceptor,
      multi: true
    }

  ]
})
```

Comment: take a look at navigateByUrl

Comment: @brk can you can share the stackbliz link /.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your response in error is **404** not **401** check the `err` in console.

```
return next.handle(req).catchError(
  (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
    console.log(err, err.status);  //<==== check here it gives err.status is 404 not 401 as you posted
    if (err.status === 404) {
      this.router.navigate(['/error']);
    }
    return Observable.throw(err);
  }
);
```

Use `pipe` to handle error on `catchError`.

> Property 'catchError' does not exist on type 'Observable>'.

so change code to this

```
return next.handle(req).pipe(catchError(  //<==== add pipe here
  (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
    console.log(err, err.status);  //<==== check here it gives err.status is 404 not 401 as you posted
    if (err.status === 404) {
      this.router.navigate(['/error']);
    }
    return Observable.throw(err);
  })
```